# How do I call a tezos smart contract over go

Tags: smart-contracts

I have deployed a smart contract to my tezos blockchain and want to interact with it.
I found the go library tzgo (https://github.com/blockwatch-cc/tzgo) to interact with the blockchain and there is an example how to get the smart contract information, but I also want to call the smart contract functions.

Does anyone know how I can call a smart contract function in go?

Thank you!